# Why am i getting phpmyadmin logo in title of fresh laravel project?

Tags: html, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.1

By default my every fresh project in laravel has title with logo PMA (default with phpmyadmin)and then my project title how can i remove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind i s to simply include in your header blade your favicon

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This the default favicon associated for `localhost` in `xampp`. Favicon is short form of **Favorite Icon**, also known as a **shortcut icon, website icon, tab icon, URL icon or bookmark icon**.

To add your own logo/favicon add that in `<head>` section. Assume you have a favicon in `resources/assets/images` folder named 'logo.png'. Your code should look like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('resources/assets/images/logo.png') }}"/>
```

The following table illustrates the image file format support for the favicon.

```
Browser | ICO | PNG | GIF | Animated GIF | JPEG | APNG | SVG
--------+-----+-----+-----+--------------+------+------+-------
Firefox | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |     Yes      | Yes  | 3.0  | 41.0
Chrome  | Yes | Yes | Yes |     4.0      | 4.0  |  No  |  No
IE      | 5.0 | 11.0| 11.0|      No      |  No  |  No  |  No
Opera   | 7.0 | 7.0 | 7.0 |     7.0      | 7.0  |  9.5 |Dropped 
Safari  | Yes | 4.0 | 4.0 |      No      | 4.0  | No   |  No
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply go to "public" folder of your project and delete "fevicon.ico" file and you all set.